# jQuery run parent function within animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a  plugin for jQuery and I need to rerun the same function after some animation has finished.  I'm trying to do this using `setTimeout()` in the animate function.

The code I'm struggling with is at the bottom is

```
jQuery(theslide).animate(theanimation,1000,function() {
        setTimeout('this.makemeslide()',3000)
})
```

the console error message is ***Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'makemeslide'*** which makes seen because this is point at the animated object.  But I dont know how to achieve my goal.

Here my full code

```
jQuery.fn.daSlider = function(options) {
    //Options
    var settings = $.extend( {
          'selector'         : 'slider',
          'width'      : 940,
          'height'     : 380
        }, options);

    //globals
    var sliderarray = [];
    var slidercount = 0;


    //Contruct
    this.construct = function()
    {
       jQuery('.slider .slide').each(function(){

              jQuery(this).css('display','none');
              sliderarray.push(this) ;

              jQuery(this).children().each(function(){
                    jQuery(this).css('display','none');
                    sliderarray.push(this) ;
                });
       });

      this.makemeslide();
    }
    //run the constuct

    this.makemeslide = function()
    {
      theslide = sliderarray[slidercount];
      slidercount++;

      way_to_slide = jQuery(theslide).attr('slide');

      slide_position =  jQuery(theslide).position();
      //console.log(slide_width);
      //console.log(slide_height);


      if(way_to_slide == 'right')
      {
        jQuery(theslide).css('left', slide_position.left + settings.width);
        theanimation = {'left' : '-='+settings.width};
      }
      if(way_to_slide == 'left')
      {
        jQuery(theslide).css('left', slide_position.left - settings.width);
        theanimation = {'left' : '+='+settings.width};
      }
      if(way_to_slide == 'up')
      {
        jQuery(theslide).css('top', slide_position.top - settings.height);
        theanimation = {'top' : '+='+settings.height};
      }
      if(way_to_slide == 'down')
      {
        jQuery(theslide).css('top', slide_position.top + settings.height);
        theanimation = {'top' : '-='+settings.height};
      }
      if(way_to_slide == 'fade')
      {
        jQuery(theslide).css('opacity', 0);
        theanimation = {'opacity' : 1};
      }

      jQuery(theslide).css('display','block') ;
      jQuery(theslide).animate(theanimation,1000,function(){setTimeout('this.makemeslide()',3000)})

    }
    this.construct();

};
```

Comment: What do you expect `this` to be? It's the jQuery wrapper object you assign these `makemeslide` and `construct` properties to.

Comment: Thanks to all who helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do never use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) with code strings to be `eval`ed! Also, your [`this` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) will not be the one from the parent function.

```
var plugin = this;
jQuery(theslide).animate(theanimation, 1000, function() {
    // "this" references theslide element
    setTimeout(function() {
        // "this" references the global object (window)
        plugin.makemeslide();
    }, 3000);
});
```

Btw, instead of a independent timeout you might want to use [jQuery's `delay` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) with a callback.

Comment: I've have a look at the delay function

Answer (score 0):

this is because
*this* in javascript is not the same as i Java.
*this* is the window-object in this case.

you can use closures to avoid this problem:

```
function Object(){
    self=this;
    this.inner = function(){


     setTimeout(function(){
        alert(self);
        alert(this);
     },100);
    }
}

var o = new Object();
o.inner();
```

Note that the second alert will show you the window-object, not the o-object